# How to make woocommerce products columns for custom shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for column argument for `WP_Query()`. As the post type will be `product`. See the code below:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'columns' => 3, // Can we have something like this
);
$loop = new \WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {  
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    endwhile;
} else {
    echo esc_html__( 'No products found', 'theme_core' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Can we have a column argument to get products per row?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question, it is really hard to pinpoint what you are asking here

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to put the row for 3 products like the below code.

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 8
);
$product = 1;
$total_product = get_products_count(); // Total Product
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {  ?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
        <?php if( $product % 3 == 0 ) { ?>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php if( $product == $total_product ) { ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; $product++;
} else {
    echo esc_html__( 'No products found', 'theme_core' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Its throwing undefined function `get_products_count()`.